# Can I use rooms in namespaces in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, node.js-connect

I'd like to know whether I can use multiple rooms withing a namespace in socket.io.

As far as I know you can use either namespaces OR rooms.

My purpose is to have multiple unique instances of my application talking with other ones with this unique application through websockets with just one node.js-socket.io-server.

Withing this application there are requirements to talk to each other. Either within a room or global. There is no need to talk to another namespace.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had no problem doing this. I have a few multiplayer games that I built ([see here](https://azurelogic.com/projects/)), and they all run on the same socket.io instance. The namespacing keeps the different games separated, and the rooms keep individual game rooms within a single game separated.

Full code example here:
https://github.com/azurelogic/CakeRush/blob/master/controllers/cakerush.js

The highlights are the fact that I use namespacing on connection:

```
io.of('/sockets/cakerush').on('connection', function (socket) { //...
```

Then later, I allow users to join a room through a 'join room' event:

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
  // find the room being requested
  var room = _.find(rooms, {id: data.roomId});

  /* skip some logic here... */

  // register player with room
  room.playerIds.push(socket.id);
  socket.join(room.id);  
  // send verification that room was joined to the player with room id
  socket.emit('roomJoined', {roomId: room.id, shouldGenerateFirstCake: shouldGenerateFirstCake});
});
```

Comment: thank you very much @azurelogic for your answer. I accepted it though, because you gave me a very good explanation and some code :)

Can you tell me how the performance will be of the node.js-server? I might get hundreds of namespaces and rooms with more of users.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never had the opportunity to really load test it. I run it on a small server (1 core, 512 MB RAM), and there have been no issues. I designed it as a standalone node.js process to be run behind nginx along with some static files, which keeps the other server load to a minimum. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again for this information @azurelogic. I'll report when my project is finished. I will try some load testings on it to determain where my bottleneck is.